# React - add and remove from state with checkbox

Tags: reactjs

I have a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jt4yuk)

It's a simple React app with a checkbox.

I'd like to add something to state when the checkbox is selected and then remove it from the state when it's unselected.

I have it working when it's selected but how do I remove it from the state when unselected.

```
handleChange = (e) => {
const array = [...this.state.colors];
const index = array.indexOf(e.target.name)
if (index !== -1) {
  this.setState({colors: this.state.colors.filter(() => {
    color !== e.target.name
  })})
}else{
  this.setState({colors: e.target.name})
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can access the state of a checkbox with `event.target.checked`.
2. Previous state can be accessed with callback version of `setState` 
   [Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-is-the-difference-between-passing-an-object-or-a-function-in-setstate)

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    const checked = e.target.checked;
    const selectedColor = e.target.name;
    if(checked) {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        colors: [...prevState.colors, selectedColor]
      }));
    } else {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        colors: prevState.colors.filter(color => color!==selectedColor)
      }));
    }
  }
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-58454785?file=index.js)